# optimising a SQL query with multiple min & max ranges

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I'm having big problems with optimizing a SQL query that is taking ages to run on a set of data with ~300,000 rows.

I'm running the query on a `stat_records` table with decimal `value` and datetime `recorded_at` column.

I want to find out the MAX and MIN values in any of the following periods: all time, last year, last 6 months, last 3 months, last month, last 2 weeks.

The way I'm doing it right now, is by running the following SQL query individually for every interval specified above:

```
SELECT MIN("stat_records"."value")
FROM "stat_records"
   INNER JOIN "stats" ON "stats"."id" = "stat_records"."stat_id"
WHERE "stat_records"."object_id" = $1
  AND "stats"."identifier" = $2
  AND ("stat_records"."recorded_at" BETWEEN $3 AND $4)

[["object_id", 1],
 ["identifier", "usd"],
 ["recorded_at", "2018-10-15 20:10:58.418512"],
 ["recorded_at", "2018-12-15 20:11:59.351437"]]
```

The table definition is:

```
create_table "stat_records", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "recorded_at"
  t.decimal "value"
  t.bigint "coin_id"
  t.bigint "object_id"
  t.index ["object_id"], name: "index_stat_records_on_object_id"
  t.index ["recorded_at", "object_id", "stat_id"], name: "for_upsert", unique: true
  t.index ["recorded_at", "stat_id"], name: "index_stat_records_on_recorded_at_and_stat_id", unique: true
  t.index ["recorded_at"], name: "index_stat_records_on_recorded_at"
  t.index ["stat_id"], name: "index_stat_records_on_stat_id"
  t.index ["value"], name: "index_stat_records_on_value"
end
```

This approach, however, takes forever to complete. I have indexes on the `stat_records` table on both `value` and `recorded_at` columns.

What am I missing here - what should I do to optimise this?

Perhaps there is some better approach where I could execute 1 query, and let postgres do the optimisations for me.

Comment: What's the table and index definition?

Comment: @Tomalak I added the table definition to the post.

Comment: I believe that you won't be able to get that query to be fast in all cases (particularly the *for all time* case). In my opinion, your only chance is to use materialized views. Then you don't get accurate values, but you can be fast.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how would that work with materialized views?

Comment: I tried to show that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index can only speed up queries that need smaller parts of a table (or sorting). So you can never expect an index to make the query over the whole time range faster.

Your solution could be materialized views. That way you can pre-aggregate the values and the resulting table is much smaller, so that queries will be faster. The disadvantage is that a materialized view needs to be refreshed regularly and contains slightly stale data in between.

An example:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW stats_per_month AS
SELECT stat_records.object_id, 
       stats.identifier
       date_trunc('month', stat_records.recorded_at) AS recorded_month,
       min(stat_records.value) AS minval
FROM stat_records
   INNER JOIN stats ON stats.id = stat_records.stat_id
GROUP BY stat_records.object_id, 
         stats.identifier
         date_trunc('month', stat_records.recorded_at);
```

If you need month granularity for your query, you just query from the materialized view rather than from the original tables.

You could also use a hybrid solution and use the original query for small ranges, where stale data might hurt more. That should be fast with an index on `recorded_at`.